# Robot localization - any minimum sensor requirements?

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will the package work fine with the most broken sensors?

Well I'm asking because I had a GPS giving noisy data , a very precise IMU with embeded filters and a very basic IMU giving noisy data.

I first fused the good IMU data with gps and had good results , but when switching to the second one I had a weird but expected behaviour , the estimated trajectory was rotated with an increasing angle.

Any way I know that I was not very precise describing the exact ammounts and the output I 've got but the point is: Is there any minimum requirements for the sensors ? , Position error for GPS ? Exact orientation ?!

I really want to hear from you guys about the sensors you have used , the good and the bad ones ... and if kalman filters are able to encounter the error when fusing noisy data? And if playing with some parameters will help when using bad sensors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255927/robot-localization---any-minimum-sensor-requirements-?/) by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't matter how accurate your sensor is if you adjust you covariance matrix for each sensor accordingly. If your covariance matrix has values indicating that the noise in the sensor is smaller than it actually is than you will get odd behavior. I once had two sensors which had more noise than the covariance matrices allowed. This resulted in the robot jumping between the two poses from the two sensors.

That being said, while robot localization doesn't care about how accurate your sensors are, robot localization can only be as accurate as the information you are giving it. If you need accuracy within +/- 5cm than you are going to need a sensor or combination of sensors that are at-least that accurate. If you are fusing noisy GPS data with noisy IMU data you are going to get strange readings.

**EDIT**

In response to the comments. Generally the process_noise_covariance and the initial_estimate_covariance default values found [on the git repo](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/params/ekf_template.yaml) should work fine.

If the sensor covariances are unknown do not set them to zero. This will make them trust the sensors too much. Instead, take a guess, try it out and modify them accordingly.If you want the robot localization to trust one sensor more decrease the covariance or vise versa.

---

Originally posted by [Nicholash Bedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29465/nicholash-bedi/) with karma: 68 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-02**:
Thanks for your answer! do you mean the sensors messages covariance or also the process_noise_covariance and initial_estimate_covariance? In sensor msg do  [-1.0, 0.0 ...] mean ignore this data and what if it is unknown [ 0.0, ... 0.0] ? is there any default values that the package uses?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-02**:
And what is the "maximum allowed noise" ?  Do I have to use perfect sensors for perfect results, or I can make some magical combinations? For example, many researchers have fused gps and IMU with kalman filters in order to correct the GPS data it self.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-02**:
I mean the combination output should be ,at least, more  accurate than the most bad sensor.

**Comment by [Nicholash Bedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29465/nicholash-bedi/) on 2017-03-02**:
I have edited my answer to respond to your comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-03**:
Thanks, it's much better now. What about the sensor's data covariances , For instance the drivers I'm using for IMU and GPS give a [0.0 ... 0.0] covariances. And I don't really know from where to get the real ones depending on the sensors, is there any common values that will work fine?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-03**:
Is there any procedure to set the covariance based on the sensor's accuracy and data sheet? and what are the allowed values?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-03-03**:
If you have the data sheet for your sensor, using the values given therein is preferred. Many sensors will state accuracy as `+/- N`, but it's not always clear what that represents, e.g., if it's one standard deviation (in which case you can just square that value).

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-03-03**:
See https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat_standard_deviation_and_standar.htm

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-03**:
Thanks Tom, I'll read the data sheets carefully and see the link you provided.
I'm done with GPS covariance using the steps provided as answer for this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/210149/covariance-specified-for-measurement-on-topic-gps-is-zero/) hopefully it will be useful for some 1

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-03-03**:
For the IMU, the covariance matrices are set except for the orientation, actually I'm using the imu_filter_madgwick, I need to check the code to see if it's possible to define its value.